# Can Lagrangian fibrations have multiple fibres in codimension $1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic, lagrangian-submanifolds, hyperkaehler

I know that if $\pi: S \to \mathbb P^1$ is an elliptic fibration of a K3-surface $S$, then $\pi$ does not have multiple fibers. A proof of this can be found in Huybrechts' *Lectures on K3 surfaces*, Chapter 11, Proposition 1.6.

I wonder if a similar result is true for Lagrangian fibrations $\pi: M \to \mathbb P^n$, where $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional irreducible Hyperkähler manifold and smooth fibers are Lagrangian submanifolds of $M$.

In [1, Example 6.9], Sawon seems to have an example of a Lagrangian fibration with non-reduced fibers. However those fibers occur in codimension $\geq 2$, whereas the set of singular fibers has codimension $1$ by a theorem of Hwang and Oguiso[2]. So precisely my question is:

> Will a general singular fiber of $\pi$ be multiple?

By "multiple" I mean (as in [2,3]) that the greatest common divisor of the multiplicities of the fibre compontents is $\geq 2$.

[1] Justin Sawon, *Abelian fibred holomorphic symplectic manifolds*, 2003, MR1975339, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404362)

[2] Hwang, Oguiso, *Characteristic foliation on the discriminant hypersurface of a holomorphic lagrangian fibration*

[3] Hwang, Oguiso, *Multipe fibres of holomorphic lagrangian fibrations*

Comment: It was conjectured by several people (Bogomolov, for instance)
that the fiber of the general point of the discriminant has no multiplicities.
Somebody told me that this paper contains a counterexample https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13127 but I don't see why.

Comment: @MishaVerbitsky Thanks for the hint. I only skimmed the paper superficially, but I think the fibers with multiple components which appear in equation (3.1) over $x \in Delta$ are not general in the discriminant locus, because $\Delta$ has codimension $3$, right?

Comment: this is what I surmised when I read the paper